# Como colocar duas <li> uma do lado da outra?

Tags: html, css

Como colocar duas (li) uma do lado da outra? Porque estão grudadas no mesmo lugar

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #23232e;
    height: 8vh;
}

main {
    background: #002df8;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 92vh;
}

.nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;

}

.nav-list li {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;

}

#main-banner {
    background: url(assets/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-position: 0 55%;
    padding: 80px;
    background-size: cover;

}

#search-form {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 15em;
    padding-bottom: 15em;
    text-align: center;
}

#search-form h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: antiquewhite;

}

#search-form p {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: antiquewhite;

}

#search-form input,
#search-form select {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

#search-form input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #01a2f3;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#search-form input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #023047;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Acervo da biblioteca</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="#">Área do aluno</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Acervo da biblioteca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="main-banner">
            <div id="search-form">
                <h1>Pesquise o livro desejado</h1>
                <p>Aqui você encontrará qualquer livro que esteja disponivel em nossa universidade</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="Livro" placeholder="Digite o nome do livro">
                    <select name="Categoria">
                        <option value="">Todos os livros</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="Gênero do livro">
                        <option value="">Todas as categorias</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A forma mais simples é utilizando `display: flex;`.

Answer (score -3):

É necessário usar uma lista? Você pode usar uma tabela no lugar, assim os botões ficam um do lado do outro.

```
 <table>
     <th>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <a href="#">Área do aluno</a>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <a href="#">Acervo da biblioteca</a>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </th>
 </table>
```